# How do I test a build release plugin without cluttering Maven Central?

Tags: sbt, automated-tests, sonatype, maven-central

I have an [sbt plugin](https://github.com/guardian/sbt-sonatype-release) designed to run the tests and if the current commit is git tagged, do some other actions including ship the artefact to Maven Central via sbt-sonatype.

I want to have an end to end test to make sure it isn't broken, so I created a dummy artefact repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/gu/ztmp-scala-automation_2.10/ and just release a new copy as part of my [scripted](http://eed3si9n.com/testing-sbt-plugins) test.

My question is how to I make the test self contained - at the moment it has a side effect I can't undo (releasing to maven central), so I have to increment the version the test ships each time.  Also, I am filling up a production repo with junk which isn't ideal.

Thoughts include having some kind of local nexus, or could I run sonatype in validate only mode but not update maven central? Then delete the repo afterwards?